# Why am I getting a "Is already defined in package unnamed package" error?

Tags: java

I am getting two error messages: one that says `class GameState is already defined in package unnamed package`
and another that says: 
cannot find symbol on this line
`this.gameStatus = gameStatus.continues;`

Here is my code:

```
public class GameState 
{
    private enum GameState {win, lose, continues};
    private GameState gameStatus;


    public GameState() {    
        initializeGameState();
    }

    public void initializeGameState() {
        this.gameStatus = gameStatus.continues;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you getting this exception? IDE or during compilation?

Comment: Look at line 1 and 6 of the code you posted... Maybe you want to delete line 6 and see if the error is gone?

Comment: My apologies, I misentered my code. Ignore line 6

Comment: @user2099971: Copy the code from your IDE, so we have your real code.

Comment: Can't have both your class and enum named the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to a specific enum with its name:

```
this.gameStatus = GameState.continues;
```

instead of

```
this.gameStatus = gameStatus.continues;
```

Also, name your enum something different than your class name.

Comment: Isn't it GameState.continues?